# ReadOnly content of RichTextBox doesn't show images

Tags: c#, image, winforms, richtextbox, readonly

I've come across some strange behavior of `RichTextBox`. I want it to be `readonly`, but then it doesn't display images when I use
`richTextBox.LoadFile(path)` method to load `.rtf` file. When it's not `readonly` the file is loaded correctly and the images are displayed. I am using Windows Forms.

Can I make it up somehow or is it another `RTB` bug? For now, as a workaround I am using a label to move focus to it while my `RTB` got focus, but I don't really like this one.

Comment: Can you share a simple code/file to reproduce the (some) particular cases and (some) images? If it's really some times and only for some images, it's really hard to reproduce the problem :)

Comment: Seems like I've expressed myself in a wrong way. The thing is that it always loads `.rtf` files, whatever kind of images they contain (.png,.jpg,etc.), anywhere in the code I open it with the method mentioned in a question. Now, when I change the `readonly` to `false` in the VS designer, images aren't displayed after using the same method. Any other change is made besides those one:)

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem, it's better to share a file and a code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've got exactly the same problem with no-image loading in "ReadOnly" state. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

you can create a custom RichTextBox implementation with a method to set RTF content which captures readonlystate, set the richtextbox to ReadOnly = false, set RTF content then set ReadOnly as it originally was.