# Loading a Rich Text Box from a file in c# winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

So in my winforms project, I have a few Rich Text Box fields. I want to load some information into these fields from a file. The file can contain text, formats, tables, and even pictures.

So, everywhere I read, to load a Rich Text Box you have to code:

```
rtbPartPlayed.LoadFile(partPlayedFile, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

However, in doing this, I get all the text, but none of the images.

If I do the reverse, and save what is in my rich text box field to a file with:

```
rtbPartPlayed.SaveFile(tmpPath + "\\" + gsPartPlayed + ".rtf", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

It saves the images and all the data to file.

How can i get it to load with the images?

Thanks
Bradley

Comment: Have you seen these QAs? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34843931/readonly-content-of-richtextbox-doesnt-show-images and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42278823/richtextbox-not-displaying-image

Comment: Curious: How did you get the images into your rtf control?

Comment: @TaW they where copied and pasted from other sources.

Comment: It may be interesting to look into the raw rtf to look for differences in how the images are stored there.. RTB is rather bad dealing with images, though.

Comment: @Dai I looked at your link, and it works. It is strange that a RTF will only load the images when readonly is false. But works. Thank you.